# add table in code first database approach during run

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have a database that has one table by default. This table holds a list of decks or a list of containers for items. Every time I enter a new deck/container entry into that table, I need to also be able to create a new table to hold that containers contents. With a regular SQL server approach I know I can use `create table` to achieve this, but everywhere that I have looked it seems that a similar feat isn't possible using Entity Framework. Is that true? If not, How would I create the tables during the program's runtime?

EDIT:

The default table will have only 2 or 3 columns(ID, Name, and Type), where the tables related to the entries in the default table will have the card details.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework is more for data access. For your above situation you wouldn't want to create an entire table per row sitting in another table, instead you'd want a linked table connected by a foreign key

i.e.

Table 1 - Containers
id | id of container
Name | name of container
Blah | all other columns required

Table 2 - ContainerDetails
id | id of ContainerDetails
ContainerId | ForeignKey to Container
Details | Details for container

Setup this way your containers can have varying data, you just need to construct the base tables in a way that will encompass all the data you will pump into it.

For instance lets say you have 2 containers, one with 3 decks and one with 5 decks, your data would end up looking as follows:

```
Table 1 - Containers
id - 1
Name - First persons Container
--
id - 2
Name - Second Persons Container

Table 2 - ContainerDetails
id - 1
ContainerId - 1
Name - First Deck for First Container
--
id - 2
ContainerId - 1
Name - Second Deck for First Container
--
id - 3
ContainerId - 1
Name - Third Deck for First Container
--
id - 4
ContainerId - 2
Name - First Deck for Second Container
--
id - 5
ContainerId - 2
Name - Second Deck for Second Container
--
id - 6
ContainerId - 2
Name - Third Deck for Second Container
--
id - 7
ContainerId - 2
Name - Fourth Deck for Second Container
--
id - 8
ContainerId - 2
Name - Fifth Deck for Second Container
```

Now from here, say i want to get all decks assigned to container 1 (using linq)

```
var query = db.Container.Include(o => o.ContainerDetails).Where(o => o.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now you have your container details and all decks assigned to it. Need to get a particular deck, just keep flowing through the id's attached to each row.

Comment: the issue with that is that the user can have a varying amount of decks and there is no way of telling how many they'll have. each card in the deck does contain the same types of data but each deck could be any combination of cards

Comment: With the method shown above your table can grow to any size, will update my answer to show the growth

Comment: but I still wouldn't be able to separate decks. I would be able to add as many cards and decks as I want, but the cards would all be in the same table or just a couple of tables

Comment: The point of sql is to separate data based on keys, you dont want 1000 tables, your data and keys do that for you, you separate by the commands you use to pull the data out. Your decks then can have their own table with another foreignKey pointing to ContainerDetailsId. You're looking at sql the wrong way for the way to pull data out.

Comment: so then it would be better to make the deck name the primary key for the secondary table, rather than create a new table for the deck?

Comment: Pretty much, you can attach as many tables as deep as you like in this way as long as you always have a "ConnectedTableId" on the child table. Then you use parent/child relations to collect all the data at once. Applying foreign keys as well means the data loads fast and with certain libraries (such as linq) you can collect every bit of data with a simple 1 line query.